# Remove a data from chrome.storage.sync?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I don't see a remove method in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) for removing a specific key. It just has clear()

But it does have a remove for StorageArea for which I don't understand the use case, to begin with.

Comment: StorageArea is `chrome.storage.sync` so you need chrome.storage.sync.remove.

Comment: So is storageArea like an interface for something for chrome.storage properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage API has several "backends" that the API calls StorageAreas:

- `chrome.storage.local` (a single-install-only storage with lax limits)
- `chrome.storage.sync` (a shared-between-installs storage area with tight limits)
- `chrome.storage.managed` (a read-only storage populated by policies)

Each is an instance of `StorageArea`, so each can use any of the described [methods](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea).